# CSS, Images, JS not loading asp.net Core :(

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This my first .net Core application. And Having issue .Well the issue is that I was adding new template to exist application and Google Console showing error that can not able to find CSS and JS

**

- Appsetting.Json

**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=MusicSite;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"



  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

    "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
      "jquery": "2.2.0"
    }

  }
```

All the CSS and Js folder are included in the Solution

[image]

Error which I am getting in Console App

**

- Console error

**

[image]

**

- Layout Page

**

```
      <!-- style -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/glyphicons/glyphicons.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material-design-icons/material-design-icons.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <!-- build:css css/styles/app.min.css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles/app.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles/font.css" type="text/css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/mediaelement/build/mep.css" type="text/css" />
        <!-- endbuild -->

  <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="libs/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- core -->
    <script src="libs/jQuery-Storage-API/jquery.storageapi.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.stellar/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jscroll/jquery.jscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/PACE/pace.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery-pjax/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/mediaelement/build/mep.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/player.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/config.lazyload.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-load.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-jp.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-include.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-device.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-form.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-screenfull.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-scroll-to.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-toggle-class.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ui-taburl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/site.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ajax.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

**

- Startup.cs

**

```
namespace MusicSite
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
            app.UseMvc();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }

            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your startup.cs code? Or please check do you have StaticFiles() middleware added.

Comment: I add my startup code

Comment: In my .min version of the file was missing. I added the path to bundleconfig.json file and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In ASP.NET core, by default, static files are served from only the `wwwroot` folder. That means if you try to access a file from `Libs` directory,  it won't work.

The good news is, You can configure the static file location as you wish. So update your `Configure` method in `startup.cs`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                                                           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     // Your existing code goes here

     app.UseStaticFiles();

     // This will add "Libs" as another valid static content location
     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
     {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Libs")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/libs")
     });
}
```

The `PhysicalFileProvider` class is defined in the `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders` namespace. So you should add a using statement to that in your `Startup.cs` class.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
```

Now the files can be accessed from `yourSiteName/libs/somejsfile.js`. Also, prefix your path to these scripts with `~/`. The tilda(`~`) signs tells that it is the app root.

```
<script src="~/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

As i mentioned earlier, the `wwwroot` is a special folder to keep your static assets together. So you may also consider moving your `libs` directory under `wwwwroot` and then everything should work fine, without the above mentioned custom configuration.

Comment: We wanted to host only files from `wwwroot`, but, odly enough, it seems when we host ASP.NET Core in the Full framework that the UseStaticFile() has to be initiated with explicitly pointing to the `wwwroot`, i.e. `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot"))
            });`

Comment: I had to flip the slashes for this to work on my Ubuntu box - `app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() { FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot").Replace("\\", "/")) });`

Comment: Is still actuality for the .net 5 I have the same issue. It can't find the statics file contained in the wwwroot folder. Even if I move the files in the root folder of the application still can't find it I'll make a post .As I'm stuck. I'll post my startup file as well.I'm depolying on ubuntu server 20.04

Comment: Put this code in your Nginx config file replace with your folder location - server {
     server_name yoursite name;
    # This location block fixed my issue.
    location ~* /(css|js|lib) {
        root /var/www/yoursite/net5.0/publish/wwwroot;
    }

Comment: @GJKH your solution worked for me asp.net core mvc, dotnet 7.